# Store multiple return values as named table keys

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a Lua function that calculates some values and returns them. For example:

```
function calculateStats()
  return { spin=1, zoom=2, rotate=3, dist=4 }
end
```

In one place where it is called I need to store these values for later comparison. Here I prefer them in a table, for namespacing purposes:

```
function foo:startup()
   self.initialState = calculateStats()
end
```

However, there's another place where this function is called many times per second. To avoid unnecessary garbage collection I'd prefer not to allocate a table for the results, instead keeping them as local variables. So now I want to switch to:

```
function calculateStats()
  return 1, 2, 3, 4
end

function foo:onRenderFrame()
   local spin, zoom, rotate, dist = calculateStats()
end
```

The unfortunate side effect of this is that I end up writing my startup function as:

```
function foo:startup()
   local spin, zoom, rotate, dist = calculateStats()
   self.initialState = {spin=spin,zoom=zoom,rotate=rotate,dist=dist}
end
```

**Is there a better way to associate indexed return values with names and store them in a table, so that I do not repeat the same names three times in close succession?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Lua 5.2, try this:

```
local function calculateStats()
  return 1, 2, 3, 4
end

function foo:startup()
   local _ENV=self.initialState
   spin, zoom, rotate, dist = calculateStats()
end

function foo:onRenderFrame()
   local spin, zoom, rotate, dist = calculateStats()
end
```

Comment: I'm not using Lua 5.2, but I assume most of the world is or will be, and this is an elegant solution. Thanks, LHF! :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple pattern you can employ is to just pass a table to `calculateStats` and then have it either return the results in the table or just return it in unpacked form. For example:

```
function calculateStats(t)
  if not t then return 1, 2, 3, 4 end

  t.spin, t.zoom, t.rotate, t.dist = 1, 2, 3, 4
  return t
end
```

This allows you to keep `foo:onRenderFrame` as is and `foo:startup` needs one minor change:

```
function foo:startup()
  self.initialState = calculateStats{}
end
```

Comment: Very elegant call syntax, thank you. :) I dislike putting extra logic in my oft-called function, however. I'm going to ponder whether the better answer is this one or the one I just added before throwing down the accept.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some 3rd party macro package like [LuaMacro](https://github.com/stevedonovan/LuaMacro) or [MetaLua](https://github.com/fab13n/metalua) to implement nice custom syntax, or use something like the following Lua code:

```
function varargsToTable( fields, ... )
  local t = {}
  for i = 1, select( '#', ... ) do
    if fields[ i ] ~= nil then
      t[ fields[ i ] ] = select( i, ... )
    else
      break -- no more known field names left, bail out
    end
  end
  return t
end

-- maps position in return value list to field name:
statsNames = { "spin", "zoom", "rotate", "dist" }

function calculateStats()
  return 1, 2, 3, 4
end


local statsTable = varargsToTable( statsNames, calculateStats() )
for k,v in pairs( statsTable ) do
  print( k, v )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is still two statements, this answers the need by removing all name duplication, without putting a conditional in an oft-called function:

```
function calculateStats()
  return 1, 2, 3, 4
end

function foo:startup()
   self.initialState = {}
   self.initialState.spin, self.initialState.zoom,
   self.initialState.rotate, self.initialState.dist = calculateStats()
end

function foo:onRenderFrame()
   local spin, zoom, rotate, dist = calculateStats()
end
```